# How to implement DELETE request using resteasy and java?

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have the current service class which provide GET, POST and also DELETE requests for a angular application:

```
 @Path("Trips")
    public class TripREST {
    ...
    ...

    @POST
    @Path("Trip")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Transactional
    public Response addTrip(Trip trip) {
        tripDao.addTrip(trip);
        return Response.ok().entity("Trip added successfully").build();
    }
    ...
   @GET
   @Path("Names/{tripId}")
   @Produces("application/json")
   public List<Names> loadNames(@PathParam("tripId") String tripId) {
    List<Names> names = tripDao.getNames(triplId);
    return names;
   }

    ...
    @DELETE
    @Path("Trip/Delete/{id}")
    public Response deleteTrip(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        tripDao.deleteTrip(Integer.valueOf(id));        
        return Response.ok().entity("Trip deleted successfully").build();
    }
    ...
    }
```

I'm trying to run the the service from browser url for testing, the POST and other GET methods working fine but the DELETE is not working and no error.

GET url working fine:

```
http://localhost:8080/jboss-seam-jpa/seam/resource/rest/Trips/Names/10000000
```

The delete url which doesn't work is:

```
http://localhost:8080/jboss-seam-jpa/seam/resource/rest/Trips/Trip/Delete/13
```

What I'm getting is the "the page is not found" error, I have debug point inside
the service method and there is no hook.

This is the service call from the angular app:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
};
...
...
deleteTrip(id: string) {    
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip/Delete/${id}`, httpOptions);
  }
```

UPDATE:
I've tested the service with POSTMAN and found that the rest api is working fine. So the problem is in the angular service call.
I realize that I didn't subscribe so I change the call to:

```
deleteTrip(id: string) {    
        return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip/Delete/${id}`, httpOptions).subscribe();
      }
```

What I see in the chrome browser concole is this error message:

```
zone.js:2935 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/jboss-seam-jpa/seam/resource/rest/Funds/Instrument/Delete/12 405 (Method Not Allowed)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2935
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1092
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2967
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1372
(anonymous) @ http.js:2366
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:23
MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:138
MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:135
MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:118
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:92
ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:51
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160
MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:92
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
MaterializeOperator.call @ materialize.js:64
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
DelayOperator.call @ delay.js:66
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
DeMaterializeOperator.call @ dematerialize.js:59
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:23
MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:138
MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:135
MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:118
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:92
ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:51
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160
MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:92
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:61
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
MapOperator.call @ map.js:57
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
InstrumentsComponent.deleteFundInstrument @ instruments.component.ts:127
(anonymous) @ InstrumentsComponent.html:139
handleEvent @ core.js:13547
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:15056
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:14643
dispatchEvent @ core.js:9962
(anonymous) @ core.js:10587
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2628
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:4740
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1517
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1543
30056021:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8080/jboss-seam-jpa/seam/resource/rest/Trips/Trip/Delete/12: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Cors filter tomcat 7 configuration:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
           <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
           <param-value>Content-Type, Accept, Authorization</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I added more info to the question, basically not found.

Comment: You have to use DELETE instead of POST/GET if you didn't so on your URL call

Comment: It's likely that you're testing it incorrectly. How are you making a `delete` request using the browser? You may need to use postman, curl, or a different client

Comment: I added the service call from the angular app.

Comment: Test it using a rest client like postman and check.

Comment: I've updated the question after testing with POSTMAN.